# Failed to deploy artifacts: could not find artifact npm

Tags: reactjs, jenkins-pipeline, nexus3

I am a new aspirant of Devops.
Most of the blogs addressed related to "404 error Not found" are of maven projects.
Can anyone explain how to resolve it for a react project?
I am trying to deploy a react project onto nexus through ci pipeline[Jenkins].

For deployment, while configuring

//Following some blogs I tried these 2 ways:

1. Configuring .npmrc file
2. Altering package.json file

But neither have worked and still halted with the error. Now, I need:

1. What can be the cause of this error?
2. Are there any other ways to resolve the error? In perspective of npm format projects

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for response
I am asking for deployment of a react project onto nexus repository of npm(hosted) format through Jenkins pipeline script.